# Is it possible for me to use string formatting or equivalent in LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, t-sql

My LINQ query has a piece like

```
where dataContext.MyTable.Any(r => $"%{r.Name}%" == name)
```

which is causing an exception

> "Method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' has no
>   supported translation to SQL

Possible to do what I'm trying to do or will I have to resort to writing raw SQL?

Comment: Why raw SQL? Just assign `$"%{name}%"` to a variable outside of the query and use it inside.

Comment: @IvanStoev, whoops, I had something backwards. Watch my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using string interpolation (which uses `String.Format` underneath), just use string concatenation:

```
where dataContext.MyTable.Any(r => ("%" + r.Name + "%") == r.Name)
```

Comment: @DrainTheSwamp - That's why it always helps to know what's going on behind the curtain when using shortcuts. Feel free to upvote/accept.